# SolrJ deleteByQuery doesn't work with cores

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying, using SolrJ, to use the deleteByQuery method and it's not working. 
Can you tell me please what is wrong?

This is working (deleteByIds):

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("id_1");
ids.add("id_2");
SolrServer solrServer = getSolrServerForCore(0);
solrServer.deleteById(ids);
UpdateResponse ur2 = solrServer.commit();
```

But this isn't working:

```
SolrServer solrServer = getSolrServerForCore(0);
solrServer.deleteByQuery("*:*");
solrServer.commit();
```

Comment: Did you get any exception? Can you post response?

Comment: The response for the deleteByQuery method is {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=0}}, and for the commit is {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=20}}. As for exceptions, I don't get any exceptions to my code, and I'm not sure how to reach for log files.
Thanks

Comment: Check application server logs directory.The query looks correct.there must be some other problem.

Comment: I can't see anything special in the logs. Do you know if the multicore example acts different than the regular example? (when i'm trying to deleteByQuery in the regular everything is working)

Comment: I added the \_version\_ field to the schema.xml and it's working now. I'm not sure why it is needed...

Comment: most probably they added new functionalities in the new version of the schema.xml

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solved the problem by adding the `_version_` field to the schema.xml

Comment: That's interesting! Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can, but you may read some more in the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Per%20Steffensen/Update%20semantics#Description)